# Does unset($_SESSION['input_name']) in if(){} clear the variable in whole script?

Tags: php, forms, session, unset

I've made the code to prevent repeating send of form. According to this code the sequence of actions is followed:
1.User submits mail form.
2.Page sends form data. Session starts. All form data are assigned to global $_SESSION variables. Mail is sent by function mail(). Variable $_SESSION['sent'] = true; is created to echo "Thank you for contacting us!".
3.Then "if" check out $_SESSION['sent'] and get that it's true...
and then the problem is arisen!
Because as I understand the next action has to be echoing "Thank you for contacting us!". And then unset() has to destroy $_SESSION['sent'] to prevent the repeat of showing "Thank ..."
But it doesn't happen and the whole contact form is shown on screen, which has to be shown only the case if $_SESSION['sent'] is not set.
So, the question is does unset($_SESSION['sent']) in if(){} destroy $_SESSION['sent'] in whole script?

```
<?php 
/* code for mailing and redirecting to the same page */
session_start();
if ( !empty( $_POST['tosendmail'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['admin_email'] = "mymail@mail.com";
    $_SESSION['subject'] = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = $_REQUEST['message'];    
    $send = mail( $_SESSION['admin_email'], $_SESSION['who'], $_SESSION['message'], "From:" . $_SESSION['email'] );
    /* create variable $_SESSION['sent'] to use condition if ( isset( $_SESSION['sent'] ) ) below */
    if ( $send ) {
        $_SESSION['sent'] = true;
    }
    header( "Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );  
}

if ( isset( $_SESSION['sent'] ) ) {
    ?>
    <h3 class="page-title">Thank you for contacting us!</h3>
    <?php       
        unset( $_SESSION['sent'] ); 
} else {
?>

    <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
    <h3 class="page-title">Contact us:</h3>
    <form class="contact-form" method="post">
        Your name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" value=""><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" value=""><br>      
        Your message:<br>
        <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="tosendmail" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"> 
    </form>  
<?php }
 ?>
```

Comment: The answer to the title would be `yes`... from anything beyond the `unset` point...

Comment: I think the problem is your mail function isn't executing. Therefore $_SESSION['sent'] isn't set in the first place. Try var_dump($send). It will probably return false

Comment: Maybe it's just continuing and unsetting the session value. Please, try adding `exit();` right after the redirect, so `header( "Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ); exit();`

Comment: @FirstOne You are definitely right!!! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$_SESSION` is a "superglobal": http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would bother with $_SESSION for that part. Your server knows if it $send is true or not.

```
if (!empty( $_POST['tosendmail'] ) ) {
        $sent ='false';
...
...

   if ( $send ) {
    $sent = 'true'; $display ='Thank you for contacting us!';
    } else { $display ='Ooops, something went wrong';} 

  if (isset($display)){echo $display; }

}
```